# Google code jam minimum scalar product not working on my selection sort (c++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I was practicing previous year's code jam problems and found minimum scalar product.
Problem Link : https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/32016/dashboard#s=p0
I know how its algorithm works. We sort both arrays v1 and v2 then multiply v1[j]*v2[n-1-j]. The algorithm works fine when I use **c++ default sort() function**. But if i use my own sorting function (selection sort), I get different output.
    Further by observing the correct output file i noticed that if all the input numbers and positive my output is correct. However for negative numbers it is incorrect.
Here is the code of my sorting function:

```
`void sorted(long long int *a,int n)
{
long long int temp;
int minIndex;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    minIndex=i;
    for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(a[i]>a[j])
            minIndex=j;
    }
    if(minIndex!=i)
    {
        temp=a[minIndex];
        a[minIndex]=a[i];
        a[i]=temp;
    }
}
}
`
```

Note that for this problem we have to use **long long int** because input numbers exceed int limits.
This is my main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
void sorted(long long int *a,int n);
int main()
{
    ifstream inp("input.in");
    int T;
    inp>>T;
    int n[T];
    long long int *x[T], *y[T];
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
        inp>>n[i];
        x[i]=new long long int[n[i]];
        y[i]=new long long int[n[i]];
        for(int j=0;j<n[i];j++)
           inp>>x[i][j];
        for(int j=0;j<n[i];j++)
           inp>>y[i][j];
    }
    long long int minProduct[T];
    ofstream out("output.txt");

    for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
        minProduct[i]=0;
        sorted(x[i],n[i]);
        sorted(y[i],n[i]);
        for(int j=0;j<n[i];j++)
            minProduct[i]=minProduct[i]+(y[i][n[i]-1-j]*x[i][j]);
        out<<"Case #"<<i+1<<": "<<minProduct[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

if i replace

```
sorted(x[i],n[i]);
sorted(y[i],n[i]);
```

with

```
sort(x[i],x[i]+n[i]);
sort(y[i],y[i]+n[i]);
```

and including algorithm header file, my output is correct.
What is the mistake in my sorting algorithm?

Comment: OT: I send you my solution just to show you, how I handle the in- and output of such exercises. I think you can save alot of time in the future if just using `std::cin`, `std::cout` and iterators. https://ideone.com/ir8CZ9

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Thank you for your time. I just wanted to why my selection sort algorithm gives incorrect sorting for negetive elements.

Comment: I encourage you to use container types from Standard Library instead of plain C arrays. Writing selection sort with using `std::min_element` and `std::swap` would be probably shorter and less error prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop where you find the minimum index, you must compare the current item at index `j` with the item at the current index of the minimum item:

```
    minIndex = i;

    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (a[minIndex] > a[j])
            minIndex = j;
    }
```

You always compare with the item at index `i` and hence don't account for updates on `minIndex`.

Comment: *Facepalm                                  Sorry for all this trouble